# Importing the same package in every module

Tags: python

I am developing an application with entrypoint myapp.py.

Now I'm trying to build a lib/package of several classes that myapp.py can use. If I import module A in myapp.py, is there any disadvantage if  several of the lib modules I'm developing all import the same module at the top of each file, or is there a cleaner, more pythonic way of doing that?

I apologize if this straight-forward or I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: There is no disadvantage.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: No problem if thousands of python modules import the same module/package. Interpreter will perform the import the first time it is encountered, and keep it in cache as long as the script is running

Comment: Thank you! if someone wants to submit as an answer I'll mark as answered